# Email notification upon ticket modification in Fossil

Tags: version-control, tcl, bug-tracking, fossil

I need to receive an email notification whenever a user creates a ticket or a ticket gets updated. Fossil has something called ticket hook, which is accessible in the UI from `admin -> transfers -> Ticket`. I have tried the following code from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg14278.html):

```
set project simpletask
tclInvoke package require http
query {SELECT title, status
        FROM ticket
        WHERE tkt_uuid=$uuid} {
   set title [tclInvoke http::formatQuery  $title]
   http -asynchronous -- http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tkt-hook?uuid=$uuid&title=$title&status=$status&project=$project
}
```

I expect this code to be executed once a ticket is modified, but I don't really know how to modify it to send an email, and how I can specify to whom the email should be sent to.

Does anyone have a sample TH1 code for sending email notifications that can share?

Answer (score 4):

TH1 is not able to do this on its own; it's too limited (and deliberately so). If you've got invocation of Tcl enabled in TH1 (it's not enabled by default) then you can use something like:

```
### THIS IS TH1 ###
tclInvoke source /some/dir/scripts/emailsender.tcl
query {SELECT title, status
       FROM ticket
       WHERE tkt_uuid=$uuid} {
    tclInvoke send_email $title $status $uuid
}
```

Then you just need to make sure that your `emailsender.tcl` script (in the above location) defines a procedure `send_email` that does what you want. You're talking about something like this:

```
### THIS IS TCL ###
package require mime
package require smtp

# Where to route messages through; IMPORTANT!
variable smtp_host smtp.example.com

proc send_email {title status uuid} {
    variable smtp_host
    set t [mime::initialize -canonical text/plain \
            -string "state is now $status for $uuid"]
    mime::setheader $t Subject "Change to '$title'"
    smtp::sendmessage $t -recipients you@example.com -servers $smtp_host
    mime::finalize $t
}
```

You'll need to pass across more fields, insert more logic to generate a message, choose who to send the message to (a mailing list is a good start!) and so on, but that's the core of it all. You may also need to explicitly `lappend` the directory containing the Tcllib packages to the global `auto_path`; that script is going to be very specific to your configuration.

---

Or you could make a script that listens to that port you push a notification to using the sample script and work with that. That would be easier to abuse though; *not recommended.*

Comment: @Donald Fellows: Your solution should work, but I have problem with auto_path. I have tried either of:

`set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 /pathtotcllib/]` and 

`lappend auto_path [file join $env(HOME) /pathtotcllib/]`

Answer (score 0):

I just followed IFTTT approach, where we used IFTTT service to connect rss feed of Fossil scm to Gmail channel. It worked.

Please refer:
http://lists.fossil-scm.org:8080/pipermail/fossil-users/2013-August/013330.html
https://ifttt.com/recipes/109526

https://ifttt.com/recipes/109526 --> is for email notification for New ticket, that can be modified (change keyword or simple phrase) to send email for any ticket modification.